# How to get HashSet limit Size?

Tags: java, performance

i wanna get HashSet Limit byte size in my develope system.

so i made just adding dump data source code

loot at my source code

```
String DUMP = "llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll";
void testSetLimitByte(){
    File f = new File("d:/test.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    int cnt = 0;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("d:/test.txt", false) , "UTF-8"));
        for (int i = 0; i<100000000; i++) {
            String dumpData = DUMP + i;

            bw.write(dumpData);
            bw.newLine();
            if(i == 0)
                continue;

            set.add(dumpData);

            if(i%10000 == 0)
                System.out.print(".");
            if(i%100000 == 0)
                System.out.print(" ");
            if(i%1000000 == 0){
                cnt++;
                System.out.println(cnt +" (size 1billion)");
            }
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(bw != null)
                bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("HashSet Limit Memory : " + f.length() +"bytes");
    }
}
```

is this code get similar HashSet limit byte size..?

Comment: There isn't a hard limit on sizes of Collections. It depends on your jvm (memory, ...). You will likely run into an OutOfMemoryError at some time.
Why do you need to know that ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is _"similar HashSet limit byte size"_?

Comment: @JimGarrison "How many HashSet adding byte in some system 
It does not occurring OutOfMemoryError" ... is that clear?

Comment: @neomega some projects need handlring big data. but i don't wanna use filesystem and DB. just do upgrade develope system or using memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HashSet is not limited by bytes, only the total heap size is limited.

Note: to reach the Integer.MAX_VALUE size of a HashSet you need heap of ~64 GB (and trivial keys/values)

> How many HashSet adding byte in some system It does not occurring OutOfMemoryError

In this case, you can find that the JVM is just running slower and slower trying to use the last portions of memory.  In newer JVMs, it detect that you are approaching this condition and dies a little earlier but it can take a long time to reach that point.